# Visual Studio ">of" command causes solution explorer to go wacky

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working with a fairly large solution right now in Visual Studio 2005 and whenever I try to use the ">of" command in the toolbar search box it causes my solution explorer go haywire.  Specifically, all of the folders start showing that there aren't any files in them anymore and I have to hit the "Refresh" button in order to get them all to show up.  This is extremely annoying so I never use the ">of" command anymore, but a jump-to-file command sure does come in handy.

Has anyone else experienced this or have a better alternative to jumping to a specific file by filename?

Note: ReSharper is not an option.  It is too slow on a solution of this size.  I tried it out and each load up took 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks for getting me to discover that you can run commands from the Find Combo box.

I haven't experienced your problem (not enough files in my solution?), but the better alternative you mentioned could be Visual Assist's 'Open File in Workspace' command. It's lightning fast for me with 2500 or so files in a solution.